# Convert Stream<Stream<T>> to Stream<T>

Tags: dart, rxdart

I am using [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package to handle stream in dart. I am stuck in handling a peculiar problem.

Please have a look at this dummy code:

```
final userId = BehaviorSubject<String>();

Stream<T> getStream(String uid) {
  // a sample code that returns a stream
  return BehaviorSubject<T>().stream;
}

final Observable<Stream<T>> oops = userId.map((uid) => getStream(uid));
```

Now I want to convert the `oops` variable to get only `Observable<T>`.

I am finding it difficult to explain clearly. But let me try. I have a stream A. I map each output of stream A to another stream B. Now I have `Stream<Stream<B>>` - a kind of *recurrent* stream. I just want to listen to the latest value produced by this pattern. How may I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the structure of BehaviourSubject ? what does map do ?

Comment: it is just a wrapper around the broadcast-stream in rxdart. see this: https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhat rare to have a `Stream<Stream<Something>>`, so it isn't something that there is much explicit support for.

One reason is that there are several (at least two) ways to combine a stream of streams of things into a stream of things.

1. Either you listen to each stream in turn, waiting for it to complete before starting on the next, and then emit the events in order.
2. Or you listen on each new stream the moment it becomes available, and then emit the events from any stream as soon as possible.

The former is easy to write using `async`/`await`:

```
Stream<T> flattenStreams<T>(Stream<Stream<T>> source) async* {
  await for (var stream in source) yield* stream;
}
```

The later is more complicated because it requires listening on more than one stream at a time, and combining their events. (If only `StreamController.addStream` allowed more than one stream at a time, then it would be much easier). You can use the `StreamGroup` class from `package:async` for this:

```
import "package:async/async" show StreamGroup;

Stream<T> mergeStreams<T>(Stream<Stream<T>> source) {
  var sg = StreamGroup<T>();
  source.forEach(sg.add).whenComplete(sg.close);
  // This doesn't handle errors in [source].
  // Maybe insert 
  //   .catchError((e, s) {
  //      sg.add(Future<T>.error(e, s).asStream())
  // before `.whenComplete` if you worry about errors in [source].          
  return sg.stream;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I will list several ways to flatten the  `Stream<Stream<T>>` into single `Stream<T>`.

**1. Using pure dart**

As answered by @[Irn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56771116/1583052), this is a pure dart solution:

```
Stream<T> flattenStreams<T>(Stream<Stream<T>> source) async* {
  await for (var stream in source) yield* stream;
}

Stream<int> getStream(String v) {
    return Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4]);
}

void main() {
    List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c"];
    Stream<int> s = flattenStreams(Stream.fromIterable(list).map(getStream));
    s.listen(print);
}
```

Outputs: `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4`

**2. Using Observable.flatMap**

Observable has a method flatMap that flattens the output stream and attach it to ongoing stream:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

Stream<int> getStream(String v) {
    return Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4]);
}

void main() {
    List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c"];
    Observable<int> s = Observable.fromIterable(list).flatMap(getStream);
    s.listen(print);
}
```

Outputs: `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4`

**3. Using Observable.switchLatest**

> Convert a Stream that emits Streams (aka a "Higher Order Stream") into a single Observable that emits the items emitted by the most-recently-emitted of those Streams.

This is the solution I was looking for! I just needed the latest output emitted by the internal stream.

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

Stream<int> getStream(String v) {
    return Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4]);
}

void main() {
    List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c"];
    Observable<int> s = Observable.switchLatest(
            Observable.fromIterable(list).map(getStream));
    s.listen(print);
}
```

Outputs: `1 1 1 2 3 4`

Comment: The solution I was looking for was the 3rd one thank you ! However, for the ones landing on this answer, the class `Observable` is deprecated, use `Stream<int> s = Rx.switchLatest(Stream.fromIterable(list).map(getStream));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Stream> to return a Stream, you basically need to flatten the stream.
The flatmap function is what you would use here

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StreamTest st = new StreamTest<String>();
    List<String> l = Arrays.asList("a","b", "c");
    Stream s = l.stream().map(i -> st.getStream(i)).flatMap(i->i);
}

Stream<T> static getStream(T uid) {
    // a sample code that returns a stream
    return Stream.of(uid);
}
```

If you need the first object, then use the findFirst() method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StreamTest st = new StreamTest<String>();
    List<String> l = Arrays.asList("a","b", "c");
    String str = l.stream().map(i -> st.getStream(i)).flatMap(i->i).findFirst().get();
}
```

Comment: The type of parameter `i` inside flatMap should be `Stream<T>`. It is not what I was looking for. I want to extract the T from the stream.

Comment: added comment if you want the first output from the streams

Comment: i need to watch the last value. But directly using flatMap on stream output seems to work: `Observable.fromIterable(l).flatMap(i -> st.getStream(i))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `asyncExpand` method on your stream - it lets you transform each element into a sequence of asynchronous events.